# Cannot find >>() and <<() declared in unnamed namespace

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The simplified example bellow illustrates the problem with the stream operators `>>` and `<<`. The example compiles in GCC10 and GCC11 with C++17 standard, but it does not compile in GCC 12.1. In GCC 12, the operators `>>` and `<<` for `ns_f::A` declared in an unnamed namespace are not found.

This is my first question, why are not the operators `>>` and `<<` found in GCC12? What has changed in GCC 12 and why has it changed?

A possible solution is to place operators declarations into the class A in the inline friend functions. But I like the version where the operators are hidden in the file.o module.

During my experimentation, I found that moving declaration of class `Wrapper` after an unnamed namespace solves the problem. This is my second question, why?

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H

#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>

namespace ns_f {

struct A { };

class Z {
        std::vector<A> items;

    public:
        void save_items(std::ostream& out) const;

};

} // namespace ns_f

#endif
```

```
#include "file.h"

#include <fstream>
#include <istream>

template<typename T>
class Wrapper
{
    public:
        explicit Wrapper(T&) {}

    private:
        using P = typename T::value_type;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Wrapper&)
    {
        return out << P{};
    }
};

namespace {

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const ns_f::A&)
{
    return out;
}

} // unammed namespace

// If move declaration of Wrapper here it compiles.

namespace ns_f {

void Z::save_items(std::ostream& out) const
{
    out << Wrapper(items);
}

} // namespace ns_f
```

Comment: That's a lot of code.  Are you sure this is a [mcve], with emphasis on *minimal*?

Comment: `wrapper.h` depends on the things declared-and-defined in `file.cpp`.  Consider declaring those things in `file.h`.

Comment: Not an answer to the Why, but I would  definitely place the operators inside the namespace of their operands. That way ADL will find them. (Once upon a time, static functions were deprecated and anonymous namespaces were supposed help with templates requiring public names. That has changed since - static is no longer deprecated and templates can very well use local names.)

Comment: [Here is a reproduction of the problem](https://godbolt.org/z/rnavqfKGa) with almost all of the code deleted, because almost all of this code has no bearing on the question.

Comment: Q#1) because they are in a different namespace, so ADL cannot find them.  Q#2) because they are then declared (and defined) so as to be available to the callsite.

Comment: @Eljay: It is not minimal. The operators for ::timespec is not needed. I included it to show that similar approach for ::timespec is working.

Comment: I think this is an example of running afoul of ADL.  ADL tries to be helpful, but can sometimes lead to puzzling scenarios.  (Titus Winters includes ADL among the list of TLA Nightmares: ADL ODR ABI UB NDR TU CPP MVP SIOF GNS IFNDR U/PIF.  As a joke, sometimes I add STL to that list to see if anyone notices.)  Related to the previously commented out code (now deleted): *hidden friends* are only accessible through ADL.

Comment: I also have a question, and my question is: why? Stick with what works. Life is too short.

Comment: Eljay: _Q#2) because they are then declared (and defined) so as to be available to the callsite._
I still do not understand, why template Wrapper should be declared after operator `<<`. Wrapper is instantiated after declaration of `<<`, so I guess the operator `<<` is already declared when Wrapper is the firstly used.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.: Honestly, because I want to understand it it how it works.

Comment: If you need to know what cryptic anti-idiomatic code does, add the language-lawyer tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using an operator like `<<` (or calling a function with unqualified name) there are two ways that matching names (i.e. here `operator<<` overloads) can be found as candidates.

The first way is by simple unqualified name lookup which traverses the scopes from inner to outer until the name is found, and then stopping.

The second is via argument-dependent lookup (ADL) by looking for it in the namespaces of classes whose type appears as part of the arguments of the function call, or here the operands of the `<<` operator.

Usually both lookups are performed from the point where the call appears and declarations which are only introduced after that point in the translation unit are not considered.

However if the call appears in a template, as is the case here for `out << P{};` there are *two* (or maybe even more) points from which lookup could be performed: The point where the template containing the call is defined and the point where a specific template specialization is instantiated.

In your code the definition of the template is before the declaration of the `operator<<` overload in the unnamed namespace and the instantiation is after it (possible points are immediately before the definition of `save_items` or at the end of the translation unit).

So, one possibility would be that name lookup is done either only from one of the two points or equally from both. But the actual rules are that the simple unqualified name lookup is performed *only* from the point of definition and the argument-dependent lookup is performed from the point of instantiation.

So your overload could only be found via ADL, but ADL requires the function to be in the same namespace as the type(s) of the argument(s), which is here not the case, since `A` is not part of the unnamed namespace.

The rules are chosen this way with the conventional understanding that you will put operator overloads specific to a given class in the same namespace and header as the class itself.

Therefore GCC 12 is correct and the previous versions were wrong to accept the code.

Prior to version 12 GCC had a bug which also considered the unqualified name lookup from the point of instantiation instead of the point of definition when looking up operator overloads for operator uses. See [bug 51577](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51577).

The unnamed namespace is a red herring, by the way. If you put the `operator<<` overload directly into the global namespace or any other namespace that isn't `ns_f`, nothing about the above changes.